# xpage button to run agent to save document

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, agent

On an xpage web application the user only has public documents read access.
I would like to find a way for the user to be able to save to a form.
I guess the most secure way is by dooing this with an agent since I read somwhere that giving write access to public documents isn't secure.

Let's say I have 2 fields : firstname and lastname .
Do I bind them to a scoped variable to have acces to them in the agent or is there a better way ?

How do I run the agent on a button click ? is following correct ?
var agent:NotesAgent = database.getAgent("(register)");

How do I give the agent the necessary authority to save the document?
And how do I get my data in my agent ? with for example sessionScope.firstName or is there a better way ?

Comment: Agents don't have access to the XPages runtime environment, so don't have access to scoped variables. The scoped variables exist within the XPages JVM running within HTTP. Amgr is completely separate even from HTTP. Since 8.5.1 (I think) you can pass an unsaved document to an agent, but there are other ways to save public documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eventually smartest way: store that data into another database at all. XPages allows you to write to a different database. If the name shouldn't be visible for other public users, then use depositor as access level

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an agent for saving a document. Use `sessionAsSigner` instead.

`sessionAsSigner` allows to run code with the permission of XPage's signer instead of the current user accessing the XPage.

Example:

```
var db:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getCurrentDatabase();
var doc:NotesDocument = db.createDocument();
...
doc.save();
```

Comment: You can also define the Form as public access and the XPage. See Mastering XPages 2nd Edition pp 1065-66

Comment: Just add a line `doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "yourFormName");`

Comment: Knut Hermann, Thanks , it seems to work this way. My only question : is it secure that way ?

Comment: Yes, of course. You as designer decide who can do what.